# Using new in a template method on any class type

Tags: c++, templates

I was trying to make a "factory" type singleton to generate components in my program. I wanted to do this centralized so that I can better control memory allocation in my program.

I wrote the following code, which compiles, but using it of course causes it not to compile because the compiler tries to write a version of it with whatever class I've fed in and the class isn't included. Is there a way to make this code work while still staying decoupled and safe?

```
template <typename T>
inline T*  generateComponent()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what goes wrong.  Please read [mcve] and try to supply one.  Note that many modern C++ styles advise against using new directly.

Comment: Minor comment here, you should be returning `std::unique_ptr` as the function transfers the ownership to the caller.

Comment: You have to include the header file(s) of all the class(es) you want to create like that in the module where you call this function. But what do you actually gain with this function?

Comment: "but using it of course causes it not to compile". This isn't really obvious in any way. Please show some code that does not actually compile, and any compiler messages that are produced.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont and and n.m. Badly explained, my bad. When a template method used in code, as it is compiled it generates a version of the method using the type specified in the function call. But because the class isn't included, as I mentioned, because I want the factory class to remain decoupled from the classes it might be asked to produce. I didn't expect there to be a way but I am still learning c++ so I didn't know if there was a way to dynamically include whatever class the template is being compiled for.

Comment: @n.m. I never provided code that would not compile because to my knowledge feeding any class that wasn't #include -d into a call of the above would always cause a compiler error, because of the way templates are compiled. I could have been more clear on that assumption/knowledge though.

Comment: @Rene I know, my question was asking if there was a way to get around that very problem. If there was a way, I could then use a factory class like this to allocate memory from a part of the stack, and have greater control. I will probably use the method stated below.

Comment: @KostasRim I have never really looked into the std::pointers and their usage but it is definitely on my learning list. Thank you for your input

Comment: Your understanding of how C++ works is not necessarily perfect, otherwise you would not be asking questions here. Please show code that doesn't compile. If there is no such code, there is no problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no direct answer to your problem, but I think what you are really searching for is an overload for `new` and `delete`. Thus, you can control the memory management as you like and keep your production code as it is.

Here is an example how to do it form [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
// replacement of a minimal set of functions:
void* operator new(std::size_t sz) {
    std::printf("global op new called, size = %zu\n", sz);
    void *ptr = std::malloc(sz);
    if (ptr)
        return ptr;
    else
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
}
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::puts("global op delete called");
    std::free(ptr);
}
int main() {
     int* p1 = new int;
     delete p1;

     int* p2 = new int[10]; // guaranteed to call the replacement in C++11
     delete[] p2;
}
```

It also works, if you use an implicit call of `new` e.g. a resize of a `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks for the code - it would certainly be another approach to the same problem and I will consider it instead of a version of the above. Thanks